# Jenkins job DSL plugin - hidden parameter

Tags: jenkins, jenkins-plugins, jenkins-pipeline, jenkins-job-dsl

I am using the Jenkins [hidden parameter plugin](https://wiki.jenkins-ci.org/display/JENKINS/Hidden+Parameter+Plugin) but I cant find the syntax to write it in DSL like I am doing with other parameters.

For example: 
https://jenkinsci.github.io/job-dsl-plugin/#method/javaposse.jobdsl.dsl.helpers.BuildParametersContext.activeChoiceParam

Is there any way to reflect **hidden parameter** in DSL?

Answer (score 13):

Job DSL has no built-in support for the Hidden Parameter plugin, so it's not mentioned in the API viewer. But it's supported by the [Automatically Generated DSL](https://github.com/jenkinsci/job-dsl-plugin/wiki/Automatically-Generated-DSL):

```
job('example') {
  parameters {
    wHideParameterDefinition {
      name('FOO')
      defaultValue('bar')
      description('lorem ipsum')
    } 
  }
}
```

Comment: This seems more precise than my answer. +1

Answer (score 0):

BEfore using the [declarative pipeline syntax](https://jenkins.io/blog/2017/02/03/declarative-pipeline-ga/) (described in [`jenkinsci/pipeline-model-definition-plugin`](https://github.com/jenkinsci/pipeline-model-definition-plugin)), you would have used:

- the [groovy-based DSL plugin](https://github.com/jenkinsci/job-dsl-plugin)
- in combination with the [JENKINS Mask Passwords Plugin](https://wiki.jenkins-ci.org/display/JENKINS/Mask+Passwords+Plugin) ([PR 755](https://github.com/jenkinsci/job-dsl-plugin/pull/755))

But with the [pure DSL pipeline syntax](https://github.com/jenkinsci/pipeline-model-definition-plugin), this is not yet supported (April 2017).

- The [PR 34 (a secret step)](https://github.com/jenkinsci/pipeline-model-definition-plugin/pull/34) has been rejected
- The following issues are still open:

  - "[JENKINS-27386: Access credentials value from workflow Groovy script](https://issues.jenkins-ci.org/browse/JENKINS-27386)" (when to be implemented in a DSL pipeline)
  - "[JENKINS-27398](https://issues.jenkins-ci.org/browse/JENKINS-27398): Pipeline-as-Code CredentialsProvider for a job" (which would at least allow you tu use credentials as a workaround to access secret values)

The last issue though points out to [JENKINS-29922 (Promote delegates of metasteps to top-level functions, deprecate `$class`)](https://issues.jenkins-ci.org/browse/JENKINS-29922) and adds [the comment](http://Promote%20delegates%20of%20metasteps%20to%20top-level%20functions,%20deprecate%20$class):

> <del>`JENKINS-29922`</del> is implemented, so assuming a `@Symbol` is defined for each credentials kind, and a credentials step is marked metaStep, you could write more simply:

```
usernamePassword id: 'hipchat-login', username: 'bob', password: 'abc/def+GHI0123='
hipchat server: …, message: …, credentialsId: 'hipchat-login'
```

> or even allow the id to be generated, and return it from the step:

```
hipchat server: …, message: …, credentialsId: usernamePassword(username: 'bob', password: 'abc/def+GHI0123=')
```

While that is encrypted, that is not exactly "hidden" though.